# How much more bandwidth is eaten up by SE in 2020 compared to 2012?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, statistics, bandwidth

Many years ago, I asked the question [How much bandwidth does SE eat up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172310/how-much-bandwidth-does-se-eat-up)

Nick Craver gave a [detailed answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172340/659728), and the short of it was a whopping 60TB of data per month!

I'm wondering how has SE's bandwidth consumption changed now?

*Web servers:*

[image]

*Database servers:*

[image]

Comment: Did you poked him on twitter ? twitter work good to poke people around these days (I tell it as I see it, only him can answer you anyhow)