# How much revenue does Stack Exchange make by auto-inserting affiliate ID into all Amazon links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, amazon, business-model, affiliate

I wonder how much revenue Stack Exchange makes by auto-inserting affiliate ID into all Amazon links.

Comment: not profit, revenue. Any given action (ads, charging employers for Careers, affiliate links) provides **revenue**. That may enable the entire enterprise to show a profit, or not, but since they are privately-held they don't need to share that information if they don't feel like it.

Comment: Why do you care about this specifically? Not sure what you are looking for to know.

Comment: Indeed, but it seems your question was inspired by a lack of really thinking about it more than anything else, so just changing profit to revenue wouldn't achieve much.

Comment: Barely enough to host all those new *quality* posts everyday...

Comment: I'm indifferent about it, but as they are privately held I doubt anyone who can know will answer your question. I'm only wondering why you want to know? What is bothering you about that ID and why is that linked to SE's revenue.

Comment: @Patrick I assume Franck means the downvote feature.

Comment: @rene this is "nice to know" piece of information. Can't see anything wrong about it. Not very different than, for example, [How much bandwidth does SE eat up?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172310/how-much-bandwidth-does-se-eat-up) which isn't a useful question, and serves no purpose other than give "nice to have" technical statistics.

Comment: @ShadowWizard hmmm, OK, but this is not *just* a technical statistic, IMO. This smells as a *you earn money due to me clicking a link, I want my share* hence my earlier comment and hence my skepticism. But I'll take your words into consideration.

Comment: Haven't disclosed it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/ but maybe now is the time for them to tell us how much money they're making rewriting user-generated content to their own ends

Comment: @random Spoiler alert: *this entire website* is dedicated to StackExchange's own ends. Ans even we non-employees are using for *our* own ends! The world is a vale of sin and sorrow :'/

Comment: We do not publicly share financial information (currently), so it's very unlikely you will get any sort of [non-extremely-vague response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217832) out of this.

Comment: @animuson You are welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @rene I think using Stack Exchange as a mere user to make money is not a good investment :-) Just curiosity.

Comment: It's common for financial records to be released during an election. So we'll just have to wait for the next one and demand that they do

Comment: Dupe: https://www.quora.com/How-much-money-is-Stack-Exchange-Stack-Overflow-making-from-Amazons-affiliate-program :)

Comment: 27. 27 revenue. Probably.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/ they make up to 10% of the money spent on the purchase, but only if Amazon considers it to be a "Qualifying Purchase". I don't know if that's what is happening here but it's probable.

Comment: OK, maybe "not relevant" wasn't the correct term. SE does have affiliate account and can earn up to 10% of money spent on purchase done after following such a link, but you can't tell by that or even estimate how much money SE actually earn from this. This fits as comment at best, not an answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Eh, it's as much of an approximation as you're gonna get without an employee revealing financials (good luck with that). Where's the harm?

Comment: @Adam no harm, but it's just a guess, actually not even a guess - doesn't feel right as answer that's all.

Comment: This is missing the significant detail that IIRC they don't just get credit it you purchase the linked item, but for *any* purchases you make from the session(?) started by that link. Been a while since I've checked the terms to be sure, but it's something like that.